# Can't execute U-SQL job that references "Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime"

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to use the "Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" dll on my U-SQL (code behind).
My problem is that i can't register the dll (because it's a system assembly), but i can't use it(because its' nto a system assembly name!!)

[image]

[image]

I'm now in deadlock...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments:

1. It seems to indicate that the system assembly is already deployed, so you do not need to reference it.
2. However, if you try to call a REST endpoint from within your custom code, please note that the Azure Data Lake containers do not allow you to call REST endpoints to avoid the potential of accidental distributed denial of service attacks against end points which could lead to these services being brought down and Azure address ranges being blacklisted.